# Samba: several users, one username

Tags: network-shares, user-accounts, samba

A quick question: will it cause any conflicts if several users, with different computers, access a Samba share with one and the same username/password combination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is - maybe.  By itself there's no problem with multiple access by multiple people with same username.  I do it all the time.  The only problem I can see is if they try to create/modify the same documents simultaneously. Obviously the programs they're going to use have to take that into account.

Hotei